# Determining program runtimes on core i5/7 architecture

Tags: c++, windows, performance, x86

When determining accurately how fast an algorithm runs in my programs, I've always used QueryPerformanceCounter() in conjunction with QueryPerformanceFrequency(), however what happens when I'm using a core i5/7 architecture?

Is it possible that turbo boost would suddenly kick in half way through my algorithm and suddenly my performance timer is no longer accurate because the frequency of my clock is no longer a constant or is this really not an issue? If it is an issue, what would be a better way to accurately time an algorithm?

Comment: yes turbo boost can kick in. Nice observation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply, Yes, anything can happen.  Modern CPU's just plain make estimating real world performance to damn hard to do.  This is not limited to just the latest Intel x86-64 cpus, it applies equally to 8bit PIC microcontrollers, and everything inbetween.

The only reasonable thing to do about it is to just test more.  You will need to perform many repeated tests to get an accurate idea about real run-time performance on real hardware for real workloads.

On the other hand, if one algorithm outperforms another on the same hardware ("on My machine") then it will usually give similar comparative results on other setups, though it may vary by a constant factor.

Comment: So really i should look at the average number of CPU cycles that an algorithm process took rather than divide by frequency and get a time in nanoseconds?

Comment: From Boost.Date_Time:
long total_nanoseconds()
Get the total number of nanoseconds truncating any remaining digits

Comment: Faken: You should really only think about the core unit you are measuring.  If the timing function returns nanoseconds, then that's what you should consider.  No point in going through any extra gyrations because they are simply not informative.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting article on the subject of **QueryPerformanceCounter**:

http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=106

Apparently, the VirtualDub dude stopped using it, and now favors **timeGetTime**.  A good read.

I recommend using **Boost.Date_Time**, specifically the **boost::posix_time** stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two separate issues here:

1. reliability of any given timing method when CPU clock frequency changes (either increasing via e.g. Turbo Boost or decreasing because of e.g. power saving or thermal management kicking in) - this is addressed in some of the other answers
2. reliability of a benchmark measurement (given a reliable clock) - this is more problematic - if you're working on optimisation and looking for small improvements, e.g. around 10%, then it's easy to get misled by the effect of clock variations from Turbo Boost at al. Possible solutions are:

   2.1. disable Turbo Boost and other clock frequency scaling

   2.2. run benchmarks for a long enough time to average out clock speed variations

Answer (score 1):

The timing source for QPC was traditionally never derived from the clock frequency.  The motherboard manufacturers have been cutting corners though, trying to shave off a penny or two.  They typically pick-off a frequency from inside the chipset somewhere.  I've heard of somebody's AMD machine that had a QPF value of 2 GHz, dangerously close to a value you'd get for the CPU clock after multiplying.  Only get nervous if you get a large value like that.

The absolute value of QPC should *never* be your concern.  It is going to heavily depend on the quality of the core.  Only ever use QPC measurements to look for incremental improvements to your code.